# Vuetify data table search by array instead of string

Tags: search, filter, vuetify.js, v-data-table, vuetify2

I'm using Vuetify data table and need to search in it. but the search in vuetify documentation is String. can I set the search to array? I wanna set filters and multiple data to search in the data table.
for example, I wanna search `x` and `y` at the same time. is it possible to put both in `search: []` and bind it to `v-data-table` search?

```
<v-data-table v-show="!map"
    :custom-filter="customSearch"
    id="mytable"
    :search="search"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="getcartables.data"
    style="white-space: nowrap; cursor: pointer"
    @dblclick:row="showDetails"
    v-model="selectedRows"
    class="box-shadow mx-5 border-radius-2"
  >
    <template v-slot:item="{ item, index }">
      <tr
        :class="selectedRows.indexOf(item.refrenceEid) > -1 ? 'active' : ''"
        @click="rowClicked(item)"
        @dblclick="showDetails($event, item)"
      >
        <td>
          {{ index + 1 }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ item.demandNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.folderNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.workflowTitle }}</td>
     
      </tr>
    </template>
  
  </v-data-table>
```

my custom-search(I'm not really using it):

```
customSearch(value, search, item) {
  return Object.values(item).some(
      (v) => v && v.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search)
  );
},
```

one of the things I wanna search in cartable is fetched like this from my v-model(I want the search to be like an array to search this renewcode and other v-models at the same time and render table based on these filters) :

```
 async renewWallPorMishe() {
  let area = this.mantaghe ? this.mantaghe : 0
  let local = this.hoze ? this.hoze : 0
  let block = this.boluk ? this.boluk : 0
  let property = this.melk ? this.melk : 0
  let building = this.sakhteman ? this.sakhteman : 0
  let apartment = this.apartman ? this.apartman : 0
  let guild = this.senf ? this.senf : 0
  this.renewcode =
      area +
      "-" +
      local +
      "-" +
      block +
      "-" +
      property +
      "-" +
      building +
      "-" +
      apartment +
      "-" +
      guild;
  this.search = this.renewcode
  this.renew = true
},
```

Comment: Can you add your `customSearch` method?

Comment: yes I'll add it in a minute